# If $\log g(x)$ ‎is ‎concave, then it has derivative ‎$ ‎\frac{g^‎\prime_{-}(x) + g^‎\prime_{+}(x) ‎}{2g(x)}‎$ ‎except.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis

‎‎Let the function ‎‎$‎g:‎\mathbb{R^+}‎‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R^+}‎$ ‎have ‎the ‎properties ‎that‎‎ for each ‎$‎w>0‎$‎, ‎$‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}‎\frac{g(x+w)}{g(x)} = 1‎$ and $\log g(x)$ ‎is ‎concave‎. ‎Now, ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎my ‎questions ‎are:‎

‎‎(a) Why if $\log g(x)‎$ ‎is ‎concave, then it has derivative ‎$ ‎‎\frac{g^‎\prime_{-}(x) + g^‎\prime_{+}(x) ‎}{2g(x)}‎$ ‎except, where ‎$‎g^‎\prime_{+}(x‏)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎g^‎\prime_{-}(x)‎$ ‎are ‎right ‎and ‎left ‎derivatives, ‎respectively ‎‎‎(I know that if ‎$‎g‎$ ‎is ‎concave‎, then $‎g^‎\prime_{+}(x‏)‎$ and $‎g^‎\prime_{-}(x)‎$ exist).

(b) Is the following inequality known‏? ‎how ‎to ‎get ‎it?‎

‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎0‎\leq ‎‎\gamma‎_g + ‎\log ‎g(1)\leq ‎‎\frac{g^‎\prime_{-}(1) + g^‎\prime_{+}(1) ‎}{2g(1)}$, ‎‎
‎

where ‎‎$\sum_{i=1}^n‎‎‎\frac{g^‎\prime_{-}(i) + g^‎\prime_{+}(i) ‎}{2g(i)} - \log g(n)‎‎\rightarrow‎‎ ‎‎\gamma‎_g‎$ ‎as ‎‎$‎n‎‎\rightarrow‎\infty‎$‎. Please guide me.